# 2 distinct integers between 5 and 17 inclusive are chosen. What is the probability that their product is odd?

Tags: probability, integers

"Suppose two distinct integers are chosen from between 5 and 17 inclusive. What is the probability that their product is odd?"

I can't figure out the probability, although I do know that both integers must be odd in order for there to be an odd product.

Thanks

Comment: What's the probability that the first selection is odd? Conditioned on that, what's the probability that the second is as well?

Comment: Note: both integers chosen must be odd.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Let $A$ be the number of pairs of integers that you can choose between $5$ and $17$.
- Let $B$ be the number of pairs of **odd** integers that you can choose from between $5$ and $17$. You might like to investigate how many odd integers are there in the range and use similar formula as the first part.
- Divide $B$ by $A$.